# armeria decorator with spring di

Tags: armeria

In my armeria project (with spring for DI),
i want to apply my decorator to specific services only.

```
@Component
class MyDecorator(
    @Autowired
    private val myRepository: Repository,
): DecoratingHttpServiceFunction {

    override fun serve(delegate: HttpService, ctx: ServiceRequestContext, req: HttpRequest): HttpResponse {
  //.. do something like authorization
    return delegate.serve(ctx, req)
  }
}
```

```
@ProducesJson
@Controller
// @PathPrefix("/a") no path prefix
class ARouter {
    @Get("/abc")
    fun sample(): String {
        return "A"
    }
}

@ProducesJson
@Controller
class BRouter {
    @Get("/bcd")
    fun sample(): String {
        return "B"
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
class Config {

    @Bean
    fun armeriaConfig(
      //..
    ): ArmeriaServerConfigurator {
        return ArmeriaServerConfigurator { serverBuilder ->
           serverBuilder
           .decoratorUnder("/", myDecorator)
           // .decoratorUnder("/a", myDecorator) no path prefix
```

The above code applies myDecorator to all routers.
Is there any way to allow MyDecorator to be applied only to ARouter? (There is no path prefix for each router.)